# viewing data stored in OpenTSDB

Tags: database, hbase, metrics, opentsdb

I have been working on OpenTSDB from past one month. I was able to create metrics and store data in the metrics. What I would like to know is..does openTSDB provide any means to view the data stored for a particular metric. Let us say I have created a metric named "EmployeeDetails" and this metric contains details of 2 employees. Now how to view those two employee details...Can anyone suggest me?

Regards
VHC

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default web interface at `http://<opentsdb-host>:<port-default-4242>` and query for the time series by providing the metric name, time frame and a set of tags to filter on.

Here are alternatives https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/wiki/Alternative-front-ends

And not to mention, you can of course use OpenTSDB APIs to retrieve time series data in JSON - http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/query/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can able to view the TSDB Data in HTTP API:
Using any Rest API CLient like postman or any,
API QUERY:

**http://localhost:port/api/query?start=&m=sum:EmployeeDetails**

For more details about REST API below.,
http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/index.html

Hope this really helpful for you